# SQL Server merge some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables in SQL Server:

**Product** table

```
id | name      | description
---+-----------+-------------
1  | Product 1 | abd
2  | Product 2 | abd
3  | Product 3 | abd
4  | Product 4 | abd
```

**Image** table

```
id | name           | idproduct
---+----------------+-----------
1  | Product1-1.jpg | 1
2  | Product1-2.jpg | 1
3  | Product1-3.jpg | 1
4  | Product2-1.jpg | 2
5  | Product2-2.jpg | 2
6  | Product3-1.jpg | 3
```

I need to select products from `Product` table including just one of the images,
and when a product doesn't have any image, show null value,

I used this code:

```
select 
    p.id, p.name, p.description, 
    isnull(i.name, 'Not available') as image
from 
    Products p 
left outer join
    Images i on p.id = i.idproduct
where 
    p.idcategory = 7 
group by 
    p.name, p.id, i.name, p.description
```

but the output is

```
id |    name   |     image       | description
---+-----------+-----------------+-------------
1  | product 1 | Product1-1.jpg  | abc
1  | product 1 | Product1-2.jpg  | abc
1  | product 1 | Product1-3.jpg  | abc
2  | product 2 | Product2-1.jpg  | abc
2  | product 2 | Product2-2.jpg  | abc
3  | product 1 | Product3-1.jpg  | abc
4  | product 1 | Not available   | abc
```

How can I change my query to select these items :

```
id |    name   |     image       | description
---+-----------+-----------------+-------------
1  | product 1 | Product1-1.jpg  | abc
2  | product 2 | Product2-1.jpg  | abc
3  | product 1 | Product3-1.jpg  | abc
4  | product 1 | Not available   | abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way uses `apply`.  If you don't care which image, you can use:

```
select p.*, i.image
from product p outer apply
     (select top (1) i.image
      from image i
      where i.idproduct = p.id
     ) i;
```

This returns a `NULL` value for image, which makes more sense to me than a string -- it is more obvious that the value is missing.

If you care *which* image is returned, then use an `order by` in the subquery.  For instance, for a random image:

```
select p.*, i.image
from product p outer apply
     (select top (1) i.image
      from image i
      where i.idproduct = p.id
      order by newid()
     ) i;
```

The order by could be for the newest or oldest or biggest or smallest or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description, isnull(i.name,'Not available') as image
from Products p LEFT OUTER JOIN Images i ON p.id = i.idproduct
where p.idcategory = 7 and 
    i.id in (select min(id) from Images i1 where i.idproduct=i1.idproduct)
```